# How to fix my CSV files? (ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-cleaning, mutual-information

I have tried to import two csv files into `df1` and `df2`. Concatenated them to make `df3`. I tried to call the `mutual_info_regression` on them  but I am getting a value error `ValueError: Found array with 0 sample(s) (shape=(0, 1)) while a minimum of 1 is required`. I have checked the dimensions of `X`, `y`, and `discrete_features`. They all seem okay.

Since the code works with other `csv` files (I have tested), I think the problem is with my `csv` files and not the code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("WT_MDE.csv", index_col=0)
df1["Interact"] = 1

df2 = pd.read_csv("M_MDE.csv", index_col=0)
df2["Interact"] = 0

data = pd.concat([df1, df2])

X = data.copy()
y = X.pop("Interact")
discrete_features = X.dtypes == float

from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_regression

def make_mi_scores(X, y, discrete_features):
    mi_scores = mutual_info_regression(X, y, discrete_features = discrete_features)
    mi_scores = pd.Series(mi_scores, name="MI Scores", index=X.columns)
    mi_scores = mi_scores.sort_values(ascending=False)
    return mi_scores

mi_scores = make_mi_scores(X, y, discrete_features)
```

[Google Drive Link to The CSV Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1L79pBY3eAVpqK2O6WtU2ONKGrkXgUBdi)

I would really appreciate if anyone could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the `discrete_features` flag inside `mutual_info_regression`. If you remove it completely (or set it to `'auto'`) it will work fine!

Comment: Oh ..Thank you so much!! I can't thank you enough. I have been stuck on this for 3 days and asked for help from many people. Finally it's working. But I wonder why it didn't work earlier

Comment: You're welcome :)